# Want to make text value Anonymous on Checkbox checked event in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Following code is not working now..don't understand the reason.

```
<td>
   <input type="text" id="txtname" ng-model="username"/>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="uservalue" ng-change="uservalue = username ? 'Anonmous': ''" /> Anonymous
</td>
```

Comment: <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtname" ng-model="username"/>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="uservalue" ng-change="uservalue = username ? 'Annonmous': ''" /> Annonymous
            </td>

Comment: Update the code in question itself, not in the comments section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("SampleController", function() {});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="SampleController">

    <input type="text" id="txtname" ng-model="username" />
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="uservalue" ng-change="username = (uservalue ? 'Annonmous': '')" />Annonymous

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MakarandDharmadhikari - What exactly are you looking for? On clicking "Anonymous" checkbox, the textbox value should be "Anonymous", right? Click on "Run code snippet" and verify this

Comment: there seem to problem in my ng-controller and ng-app.. can you help me to understand one thing...can i use same JS file with two different controllers from two different HTML pages? using more than one HTML page does mean that iits not a single page application, is it like that

Comment: got the problem..had some mis understading about controller and app..thanks for your help

Comment: @MakarandDharmadhikari - happy to help :)